# Tkinter: clicking buttons in menu is triggering function with wrong argument

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface, tkinter

Hi,
Im struggling with strange for me error, so I want to have buttons in cascade menu, and each of them should trigger function, passing they name to it.

The code is as follows:

```
from tkinter import *

def say_hi(name):
    print(name)

root = Tk()

menu = Menu(root)
root.config(menu=menu)

subjects_menu = Menu(menu)
menu.add_cascade(label="Subjects", menu=subjects_menu)

d = ["name1", "name2"]
for name in d:
   subjects_menu.add_command(label=name, command=lambda:say_hi(name))

'''
this is also not working

name = "Math"
subjects_menu.add_command(label=name, command=lambda:say_hi(name))
name = "Physics"
subjects_menu.add_command(label=name, command=lambda:say_hi(name))
'''

root.mainloop()
```

So I want to print name of clicked button in console, and add buttons by iteration, not one by one (I cannot predict number of them)

After running program I get no errors, and window shows. Whichever button I click, console prints "name2".
I did add few more names - it always prints name of the last option.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lambdas are tricky, but you can do what you want to do with a lambda argument:

```
for name in d:
   subjects_menu.add_command(label=name, command=lambda x=name:say_hi(x))
```

This should solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Another (IMO neater) way to do this is to use `functools.partial`:

```
from functools import partial

for name in d:
   subjects_menu.add_command(label=name, command=partial(say_hi, name))
```

Comment: Good info. Lots of good stuff buried in the functools module.

Comment: I agree with 'neater'